# Remove timezone conversion from the value of ui:inputDateTime

Tags: lightning-aura-components, datetime, timezone, guest-user

I have a public community which means that guest users will be sharing the same guest user record (But not all users will be guest). I am trying to create a way to for them to enter a dateTime and send it back to the server. It looks like ui:inputDateTime automatically converts the selected dateTime using the timezone on the user record.

Example 1:

- User Time Zone (on Salesforce user record) = GMT
- `<ui:inputDateTime>`: user enters January 26 12:00 PM
- value =2017-01-26T12:00:00.000Z

Example 2:

- User Time Zone (on Salesforce user record) = EST
- `<ui:inputDateTime>` user enters January 26 12:00 PM
- value = 2017-01-26T17:00:00.000Z

As guest users will be sharing the same record , I am trying to use moment.js to convert the time to utc using the utc-offset of the browser.

```
 var dateTime=component.find("UIdateTimeCmp").get("v.value"); 

 var convertedNewTime = moment(dateTime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

This worked when I tried using `lightning:input type="Datetime-local"` but then I discovered IE and firefox don't support it so I am switching to `ui:inputDateTime.`

The "z" makes moment think that the time is already in GMT so there is no conversion. A workaround for this I came up with is that If I know the user is a guest user and I know that the guest user record has a GMT timezone, I found that I could slice the z before converting.

```
 var dateTime=component.find("UIdateTimeCmp").get("v.value"); 
 dateTime= dateTime.slice(0,-1);
 var convertedNewTime = moment(dateTime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

But then this messes things up for users who are not guest users and do not have the GMT timezone on their record.

```
//salesforce timezone = EST
//User enters 12:00 PM. (Utc time should be 17:00:00)

var dateTime=component.find("UIdateTimeCmp").get("v.value"); //2017-01-26T17:00:00.000Z
dateTime= dateTime.slice(0,-1); 
var convertedNewTime =  moment(dateTime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // 2017-01-26T22:00:00
```

I need a way to get the actual value the user sees in the datepicker rather than the value converted to the user record's timezone, so that I can use moment.js to convert the value to the browser's utc-offset.

Comment: if you are able to identify the user is a non-guest user, have a flag something like `isGuest` as a aura:attribute and skip the timezone conversion logic if its value is `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lightning Framework has a localization service that you can use in your JS to format date/time values which should be helpful to you with your issue.

```
// get currrent date/time and localize based on user's browser settings

var dateFormat = $A.get("$Locale.dateFormat");
var dateString = $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(new Date(), dateFormat);


// explicitly format date/time value

var dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a";
var userLocaleLang = $A.get("$Locale.LangLocale");
return $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(date, dateFormat,userLocaleLang);
```

Comment: Thanks! I read through the documentation on localization service. I'm a little confused though , it sounds like it can only get information from the user record in salesforce. What browser specific information does it use?

Comment: There are a variety of ways, none of which are ideal. Choose your poison from this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference or this informative blog post: http://blog.ksol.fr/user-locale-detection-browser-javascript/