# How to set the time for inputdatetime tag?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

By using below code i can be able to set the date for inputdatatime component

```
var today = new Date();
        component.set('v.today', today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate());
```

but unable to set the time,have tried too many ways to do that without success. Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried appending time in the below ways, and it worked for me:

**Hardcoded Time Format:**

```
component.set('v.today', today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate() +"T15:30:00");
```

**Appending Current Time:**

```
component.set('v.today', today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate() +"T" + today.getTime());
```

> Append T after the date and enter the time as shown in the
>   hardcoded format.

You can format and change the code it as per your requirement

Comment: thanks for your reply,  It should display 3:30Pm but able to see 3AM.  I think Timezone is an issue  here, how can i do that?

Comment: Check this link: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157597/remove-timezone-conversion-from-the-value-of-uiinputdatetime